# Is there a FreeDesktop command to open an open-with dialog similar to xdg-open?

Tags: desktop-environment, freedesktop, file-opening, xdg-open

is there a (FreeDesktop) Linux command to open an "open-with" dialog similar to `xdg-open`?

I'm searching for some general desktop environment independent solution for showing something like this:

[image: Dolphin's open-with dialog]

Of course there is `xdg-open` to open the file with the default app, but how do I give users a choice to open a file in a different app?

I'm also not looking for `mimeopen` that changes the current default application.

Answer (score 1):

`mimeopen` is what you're looking for.  Specifically `mimeopen`'s `-a` or `--ask` option.

From the man page:

```
   -a, --ask
       Do not execute the default application but ask which
       application to run.  This does not change the default
       application.
```

Otherwise, it depends on your desktop environment and/or file browser.  For example, `xfce`'s `Thunar` file browser has an `Open With" option when you right-click on a filename, which displays a menu with all apps known to be capable of opening the file's filetype.  The final menu item is "Open with Other Application" (which optionally lets you change the default).

Comment: Executing something like ```xterm -e "mimeopen -a myfile.txt"``` from an end-user GUI application looks really ugly :(.  Regarding ```Thunar```, I've attached a screenshot of the open-with dialog from ```dolphin```, but I couldn't find a desktop-environment agnostic way to show this dialog.

Comment: that's because the dialog is specific to dolphin.  As i said, it depends on your desktop environment and your file browser because it is those programs that implement the feature (or not), and each does it differently.