# How to raise the system native OpenWith dialog for a particular file?

Tags: xdg-open

The `xdg-open` command opens a file specified with the default app associated with the type. Is there an alternative that would raise the system native application choice dialog (which pops up when you right-click a file and select "Open With...") instead?

Comment: Related: [Is there a FreeDesktop command to open an open-with dialog similar to xdg-open?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268885/125388) suggested `mimeopen -a` that asks like "open with" in terminal and not GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xdg-open is designed to open files and web pages in the user's default application. I see no option to do otherwise.

The man-page shows:

```
Description

xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a URL is
provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web browser. If a file
is provided the file will be opened in the preferred application for files of
that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http and https URLs.
```

Alternative:

[xdotool](https://askubuntu.com/a/49155/894044)

Of course, you will have to amend the alias to match your settings to bring up that dialog box.

Also:

```
gnome-panel-control --run-dialog
```

If not installed install it, if it can be installed.

Comment: Any alternative? I don't insist to use xdg-open (I just couldn't imagine a better tag).

Comment: Added Alternative...

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't really suit my case nicely but seems a valid answer to the question.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I'm writing a PyQT app that, among other features, would let you open a particular file in an application you choose. I thought it could be nice to outsource this to the system but it seems I better just parse the system MIME/apps database and populate a list. Two of the goals of the app design are to require zero installation (just a single py file to copy around) and to be cross-platform, depending on an X11 keyboard/mouse input simulator doesn't really suit this.

Comment: Could you take advantage of VISUAL vs EDITOR type environment variables, to leverage the options you present to the user?

Comment: The file can be of absolutely any type, not necessarily plain text.

Comment: I was just thinking you could make it so the script looks for what is available on the system (not every program but say from a pool of 5 or so known apps for each of the main file types your expected user-ship will be opening) it then creates its own menu to present and opens the file with the chosen application.